# Doing Riemann Sum with Discrete Points in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, integral

I have a dataset consisting of many points (around million~trillion), which maps
[x1, x2, x3] to a vector [y1, y2, y3]
I want to compute Riemann Sum of this function.

I don't know if this helps, but all x1, x2, x3 are bounded by [0,1].
Is there a Python module or a simple way for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program that computes the left Riemann sum. This assumes that the values given in the vector are sorted in increasing order of x-value.

```py
integral_value = 0
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    width = x[i + 1] - x[i]
    
    # Replace with y[i + 1] for right Riemann sum.
    # Or, replace with (y[i] + y[i + 1]) / 2 for midpoint Riemann sum.
    height = y[i]
    integral_value += width * height
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the X values in the OP's question are not evenly spaced. In that case, I do it with pandas. First simulate the OP data:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

dx1 = 10**(-8)
dx2 = dx1*0.3
X = np.sort(np.concatenate((np.arange(0,1,dx1),np.arange(dx2,1,dx2))))
X = X[np.concatenate(([True],np.diff(X) > 10**(-15)))]
Y = np.pi*np.sin(np.pi*X)/2
```

Then, with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Place everything in a dataframe. X is placed directly in the index.
data = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns = ['Y'], index = X)
# New columns with the intervals between dx and the average of pairs or consecutive points
data['dx'] = pd.Series(data.index-data.index[0]).diff().values
data['2pt_average'] = (data['Y'] + data['Y'].shift(1))/2

print('Integral:',(data['dx']*data['2pt_average']).sum())

> Integral: 0.9999999999999907
```

This exploits the optimised loops in pandas. It's probably one of the quicker ways. I could reduce dx to 10^(-8) which leads to 400 million data points. Going to the trillion scale will be harder.

You can be a bit more efficient if you skip the definition of the 'dx' and '2pt_average' columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns = ['Y'], index = X)
print('Integral:',((pd.Series(data.index-data.index[0]).diff().values)*((data['Y'] + data['Y'].shift(1))/2)).sum())

> Integral: 0.9999999999999907
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical calculations in python are greatly facilitated by using `numpy`. If we have a list with x values `x=[x0, x1, ..., xN]` and a list of function values `f=[f1, f2,..., fN]` then the code is something like follows:

```
import numpy as np

xx = np.array(x)
ff = np.array(f)

S = np.sum(np.diff(xx)*ff)
```